# How do you customize the copy/paste behavior in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, copy-paste

How do you customize the Copy/Paste behavior in Visual Studio 2008?

For example I create a new `<div id="MyDiv"></div>` and then copy and paste it in the same file.

VisualStudio pastes `<div id="Div1"></div>` instead of the original text I copied.

It is even more frustrating when I'm trying to copy a group of related div's that I would like to copy/paste several times and only change one part of the id.

Is there a setting I can tweak to change the copy/paste behavior?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Go into Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML > Miscellaneous and uncheck "Auto ID elements on paste in Source view"

Comment: I just found that. The only drawback is it doesn't handle ID at all now in source view. So if you drag & drop a GridView or some other element you have to make sure to add an ID.

Comment: While I can see how that can be bad when trying to rapidly prototype, I almost feel like it should be the standard setting for production code development. Too may a times I've seen CheckBox1, CheckBox2, etc. in production code that needs some maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2019
the new location is
`Tools > Text Editor > ASP.NET Web Forms`
and Check `Format HTML on paste`.
So now it is possible to efficiently duplicate sequential ID codes.