# Prevent ID autogeneration on copy-paste in Visual Studio 2008 ASP.NET Web Form

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, copy-paste

If I have the following in an ASP.NET Web Form:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbxUser"/>
```

and I copy and paste that line in the same page, I usually get the following:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1"/>
```

Obviously, nobody is going to name their controls in that way (if you don't want to name a textbox, simply don't asign an ID to it), and it's not nice having to change the ids of pasted controls. The same happens if I copy a control without an explicit ID, VS simply generates one for me.

Is there any way of preventing VS from autogenerating IDs when I copy-paste ASP.NET code?

Comment: Great question, this really bugs me!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I prevent Visual Studio from renaming my controls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484327/how-do-i-prevent-visual-studio-from-renaming-my-controls)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Options, Text Editor, HTML, Misc, Auto ID on Paste

By the way, [the most similar article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67209/how-do-you-customize-the-copy-paste-behavior-in-visual-studio-2008) contains just the same question (answered, of course). Be more careful next time :)

Comment: weird, when I was writing the question I couldn't see that question in the similar questions list. Thanks for the link :)

Comment: FYI - regardless of what duplicates exist on stackoverflow, this one still ranked higher on Google when I searched for "visual studio disable pasting with IDs".

Answer (score 3):

If you're on Visual Studio 2013, see this stackoverflow question:

[Disable "Auto ID elements" in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695992/disable-auto-id-elements-in-visual-studio-2013)

which basically points to a bug raised with Microsoft (disabling auto id has been removed from VS 2013):

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806446/asp-net-web-forms-development-unable-to-disable-auto-id-generation-on-paste-using-new-version-of-visual-studio-2013

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio 2017 doesn't seems to have a way to turn this off. If anybody knows the way, kindly post for VS 2017. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Funny how this post is 12 years old, and at that time there was actually a solution to fix it.
Fast forward to the year 2022, and a function that great has been removed by Microsoft.

The only workaround I've found online on how to do this is basically to ***'fool'*** the IDE into thinking that ***"we're not pasting code."***

Meaning that the best solution so far is to:

1. Comment out the code **(ctrl+k, ctrl+c)**
2. Copying that and pasting it where you'd like it to be.
3. Uncomment the pasted code **(ctrl+k, ctrl+u)**

Who removes a function that works? ***@Microsoft***

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround ...
copy part of tag .
for example:

and then add the close tag ">" manually.

Best Regards'

Comment: <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbxUser"/