# How to disable Visual Studio "smart" way to replace IDs in markup

Tags: visual-studio-2010

From the hundreds of Visual Studio options, is there one to disable the way VS replace the IDs in markup when copy&paste from other control?

Almost always only need to change a few characters but VS thinks he is being smart replacing all the ID

Comment: I'm sure this isn't the answer you want (thus its a comment), but a quick undo will revert your paste to the original text in your clipboard.  This has been a source of great frustration to me as well.  I'd love to see good permanent answers to it.

Comment: Sam: good to know that too, but the permanent version is better! See below

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go into Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML > Miscellaneous and uncheck "Auto ID elements on paste in Source view"

source:
[How do you customize the copy/paste behavior in Visual Studio 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67209/532498)
but in 2010 it is the same

Comment: This option seems to be gone for visual studio 2013... or at least I cannot find it :(